# How Can We bound the Selected Data From DropDownList With textbox in MVC View?

Tags: razor, view, asp.net-mvc-views

> I need to put value in textbox when i select the dropDownlist item....
>   If there is way to do so.... Regards

```
      <div class="form-group"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GenreType, new
         { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }) <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GenreType) 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GenreType, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof
(GenericLib.GenreTypes))))
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenreType) </div>
```

Comment: I mean, need help to modify @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.GenreType) code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this with helper class,,,,